# Gnome Shell Extension Key Binding

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, shell-extensions, gnome-shell

**What is the simplest way to (globally) bind a key combination (e.g. `<Super>+A`) to a function in a gnome shell extension?**

Inspecting a couple of extensions, I ran into the following code:

```
global.display.add_keybinding('random-name',
                              new Gio.Settings({schema: 'org.gnome.shell.keybindings'}),
                              Meta.KeyBindingFlags.NONE,
                              function() { /* ... some code */ });
```

I understand that the key combination is specified by the schema parameter, and that it's possible to create an XML file describing the combination. **Is there a simpler way to do this?**

Comment: If you are creating a GNOME shell extension then you would probably get better responses on [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/). Flag for moderator attention and they should migrate your question.

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DR

Here is a class:

```
KeyManager: new Lang.Class({
    Name: 'MyKeyManager',

    _init: function() {
        this.grabbers = new Map()

        global.display.connect(
            'accelerator-activated',
            Lang.bind(this, function(display, action, deviceId, timestamp){
                log('Accelerator Activated: [display={}, action={}, deviceId={}, timestamp={}]',
                    display, action, deviceId, timestamp)
                this._onAccelerator(action)
            }))
    },

    listenFor: function(accelerator, callback){
        log('Trying to listen for hot key [accelerator={}]', accelerator)
        let action = global.display.grab_accelerator(accelerator)

        if(action == Meta.KeyBindingAction.NONE) {
            log('Unable to grab accelerator [binding={}]', accelerator)
        } else {
            log('Grabbed accelerator [action={}]', action)
            let name = Meta.external_binding_name_for_action(action)
            log('Received binding name for action [name={}, action={}]',
                name, action)

            log('Requesting WM to allow binding [name={}]', name)
            Main.wm.allowKeybinding(name, Shell.ActionMode.ALL)

            this.grabbers.set(action, {
                name: name,
                accelerator: accelerator,
                callback: callback,
                action: action
            })
        }

    },

    _onAccelerator: function(action) {
        let grabber = this.grabbers.get(action)

        if(grabber) {
            this.grabbers.get(action).callback()
        } else {
            log('No listeners [action={}]', action)
        }
    }
})
```

And that's how you you use it:

```
let keyManager = new KeyManager()
keyManager.listenFor("<ctrl><shift>a", function(){
    log("Hot keys are working!!!")
})
```

You're going to need imports:

```
const Lang = imports.lang
const Meta = imports.gi.Meta
const Shell = imports.gi.Shell
const Main = imports.ui.main
```

To stop listening:

```
for (let it of keyManager.grabbers) {
    global.display.ungrab_accelerator(it[1].action)
    Main.wm.allowKeybinding(it[1].name, Shell.ActionMode.NONE)
}
```

### Explanation

I might be terribly wrong, but that what I've figured out in last couple days.

First of all it is Mutter who is responsible for listening for hotkeys. Mutter is a framework for creating Window Managers, it is not an window manager itself.
Gnome Shell has a class written in JS and called "Window Manager" - this is the real Window Manager which uses Mutter internally to do all low-level stuff.
Mutter has an object MetaDisplay. This is object you use to request listening for a hotkey.
But!
But Mutter will require Window Manager to approve usage of this hotkey. So what happens when hotkey is pressed?
- MetaDisplay generates event 'filter-keybinding'.
- Window Manager in Gnome Shell checks if this hotkey allowed to be processed.
- Window Manager returns appropriate value to MetaDisplay
- If it is allowed to process this hotkey, MetaDisplay generates event 'accelerator-actived'
- Your extension must listen for that event and figure out by action id which hotkey is activated.

Comment: I've tested this code only in Gnome 3.22

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks so much for sharing this.

Comment: Where does global come from? Which library is it part of?

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!  What is the license for the code?  Would you be willing to license it BSD or MIT, by any chance?  I appreciate your considering this request!

Comment: @borizzzzz I'm not sure right now, it's been 3 years but global comes from Gnome JS runtime.

Comment: @cxw I'm not sure what kind of weight it has here but sure I consider it to be public domain, in other words - do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @p2t2p Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

`gconf-editor` might do what you want: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/)